# WebSphere Jython createWMQConnectionFactory NullPointerException with -connectionNameList option

Tags: websphere, jython, ibm-mq

According to the IBM docs, below is the proper way to script a Queue Connection Factory using Jython.  However, whenever the -connectionNameList option is added, I'm getting a NullPointerError.  If I remove -connectionNameList, or if I put an empty string in place of the hostnames, the errors go away.

We're using WebSphere 8.5.5.9

This is line 335 (I replaced the hostnames):

```
 AdminTask.createWMQConnectionFactory(scopeID,'[-type QCF -name someQCF -jndiName jms/someCF -wmqTransportType BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT -qmgrSvrconnChannel SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN -qmgrHostname -connectionNameList host(1234),host(1234) ]')
```

And the error:

```
Exception caught during execution:
type <java function type at 613319364>
value com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException

tb Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 383, in install_server
  File "<string>", line 335, in createWMQConnectionFactory
```

**Update:** These commands work when ran directly from the wsadmin> prompt.  However, when ran from a python script using jython, they do not and instead return the NullPointerException as displayed above.

Comment: That looks OK to me.  When you use the dummy host(port) of: host(1234),host(1234)  does the error still occur?

Comment: @ScottKurz yes. I've tried every combination I can possibly think of.  I'm beginning to conclude it's a bug on their end, but that doesn't really help my situation much.

Comment: Raise a PMR to have IBM provide you with a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue.

A script I had been given to run this had the

```
-conntype NONE
```

option set on ./wsadmin.sh

I removed that and it works now.  It's very strange that the option only affected that one function.

Comment: Local mode (-conntype NONE) has numerous limitations and affects other tasks and operations, see IBM KnowledgeCenter topic http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminapp.html as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the variable scopeID contains an invalid config id.  Look in the ffdc directory of the profile where you're trying to create the MQ Conn Factory.  If you see something like this:

> ```
> [6/29/16 7:40:04:169 MDT]     FFDC Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```
>
> SourceId:com.ibm.websphere.management.async.client.AsyncCommandClient.execute
>   ProbeId:187 Reporter:java.lang.Class@7e78ccb4
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.ConfigServiceHelper.getObjectLocation(ConfigServiceHelper.java:258)
>         at com.ibm.ws.messaging.admin.command.WMQCommandHelper.checkScope(WMQCommandHelper.java:156)

your scopeID variable is not valid. Looking at an IBM KnowledgeCenter [topic related to wsadmin](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_specifyconfig.html), here's how to obtain the value for scopeID:

```
scopeID = AdminConfig.getid('/Node:mynode/')
```

where you replace the Node:mynode with the appropriate scope value for your configuration.  If you print the value of scopeID in your script before calling the AdminTask you'll be able to see if it is properly formed.  Here's an example of a valid cell scoped config id:

```
wsadmin>print scopeID
MyNode03Cell(cells/MyNode03Cell|cell.xml#Cell_1)
```